# Передача аргумента скрипту в HTML

Tags: html, функции

Есть поле ввода кода и кнопка `Добавить`. Кнопка берет значение с поля ввода, а как сделать так, чтобы отдельная кнопка передавала свое значение? Т.е. пользователь вводит код курса и добавляет его к себе. А как сделать кнопку, которая добавит определенный курс?

Вот поле ввода кода:

```
<div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" id="group-id" class="form-control" placeholder="Введите сюда код класса. Например: 182967">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" onclick="groupsAdd()">Добавить</button>
      </span>
    </div>
```

А вот скрипт выполнения:

```
function groupsAdd(gid){
    var gid = trim($('#group-id').val());
        $.ajax({
            type:'post',
            url:'/func_student.php',
            dataType:'json',
            data:{'action':'groupsAdd','gid':gid,'user_id':user_id},
            success:function(j){
                var r = j['r'];
                if (r != 200){
                    var txt = '';
                    if (r == 1) txt = "Вы неверно ввели код группы";
                    else if (r == 2) txt = 'Вы уже состоите в этой группе';
                    swal({
                        title: "",
                        text: txt,
                        type: "error"
                    });
                } else {
                    window.location.href='';
                }
            }
        });
}
```

Вот что я хочу исправить:

```
<button class="btn btn-default" type="button" id="group_id" value="1481472" onclick="groupsAdd()" >Пробный урок</button>
```

Comment: Дополните свой вопрос кодом с Вашими попытками. Это не место, где за Вас сделают то, что Вы хотите...

Comment: @VladimirGonchar проссмотрите пожалуйста

Answer (score 3):

Как вариант- использование `data-атрибутов`, если у вас у курса id=45 к примеру, то будет так:

```js
$('.data').click(function(){
  console.log($(this).attr('data-id'));
});

$('.value').click(function(){
  console.log($(this).attr('value'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class='data' data-id='45'>Курс №45</button>
<button class='data' data-id='4'>Курс №4</button>

<button class='value' value='45'>Курс №45 по value</button>
<button class='value' value='4'>Курс №4 по value</button>
```

Comment: в моем случае он, видимо берет значение с поля ввода.

Comment: @neomendax В вашем случае можно использовать `$('#group-id').attr('value')`

Comment: так у меня поламался и самостоятельный ввод

Comment: @neomendax обновил ответ, ничего не ломается по value

Comment: это ведь в `<script>` приписывать?

Comment: @neomendax Верхний блок кода да, нижний обычный HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Я попробовал передать аргумент через скрытое поле ввода.

```
    <input type="hidden" value="123" id="group-id">
<button class="btn btn-default" align="center" type="button" onclick="groupsAdd()">Пробный урок</button>
```

это не потребовало никаких изменений в другой части кода.

Comment: как оказалось, этот метод не совсем работает. так как у меня 6 полей с 6 разными значениями, то при получении значения `input` ->`value`, все значения конкатенируются. но функция забирает себе только первые х символов, так что при нажатии любой кнопки, выполняется только первое значение.